Motorhome Rear drivers side brake, needs temporary fix
The motorhome is currently our temporary home and at any given moment we will have to move it, especially in case of emergency as we are not too far from a naval air base and potential bad storms. The brake light on the dash stays on. The leak is not a hemorrhage the fluid leaks about maybe a small bottle of brake fluid or so  over more than a month. This is just from starting the motor. This is not the typical brake system as it has a hydraulic assist that works with the power steering system. My quandary is that I am not able to get a mechanic to fix on site and because we are living in it I cannot take it to a shop. Once we had another class A motorhome and it needed a lot of work and so we stayed in a extended stay while it was being repaired, but unfortunately we don't have that option right now. So in order to move it to a different location where it will stay until we transition to another newer RV or house. I'm trying to come up with a temporary fix to repair the line.
Some options I'm exploring are silver solder to plug the leak which also has to be heated. In order for thee to be a safe environment to do that I need to remove or bleed all fluid that is in the lines. I can turkey baste what's inside the master cylinder reservoir and I figured I can bleed the line by just letting it leak out as it's been leakingupbtill now I have yet to find any mention of this online. The bleeder valve is likely rusted and would have to be cut off and replaced so I don't even want to consider doing the bleeding by way of the valve there's another option I'm open to explore it. The next option is to cut the line where the leak is and splice in a brake line repair kit with the proper brake fitting. The line should fit inside the existing line, it's a complicated process since the hole is very close to the area of the brake shoes cylinder. I realize that a temporary fix isn't going to be the best option but at the moment it's the only option that I have available. My only experience with splicing lines so far is repairing my transmission line that was leaking. One of the temporary fixes that I've used in the past is JB weld or JB steel it has held up but in this case the PSI is much higher and will probably not hold up. I have to confess I already have put JB weld or actually the equivalent of from harbor freight where the line is leaking in the hopes that it would stop leaking but that's not the case so now I will most likely have to file off the JB weld in order to be able to put the silver solder on and heat it up. I can really use some advice here and I'm hoping I can get this done soon for the next storm poses a threat. Thanks Edit meant to add photo, added now.[![enter preformatted text here][1]][1]

You may be describing an unconventional repair that may not be safe. Can you post some snapshots of the leak?

Consider using gaffer tape or duct tape for a quick temporary fix as the storm approaches. What is the relevance of a nearby "naval air base"?

I hadn't considered that, I will make sure I have some hand. To answer your question, the significance of the air base, is the potential for a mishap in the area has grown exponentially as the t-45 trainers have a very serious flaw with the Rolls Royce engine blades that are now 30 years old and thiere have been multiple incidents and mishaps at more than 1 base. This is in the media and I also have this on good  authority from an aerospace engineer who is currently working on the problem. The Navy has passed a 1 millionth flight milestone and they don't want to replace them  yet with T-38s

My mistake not T-38s it's T-7A Red Hawk replacement trainer.i posted a photo of the leak in OP
